# How to underline an unanchor text?

Tags: html, css

I have this issue since I have learned a lot in HTML and CSS. What I just do is this:

HTML:

```
<div>
  MY NAME HERE
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom: (desired width) solid (desired color);
}
```

```css
div {
font-size: 30px;
display:inline-block;
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
MY NAME HERE
</div>
```

Am I doing right, or is there an easy way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The underline is working just fine.

Comment: It may look fine but what I am here for is the easier way or the correct way

Comment: Define easier? And using the border is perfectly correct.

Comment: Well, thanks then for reminding me. Wish you luck!

Comment: If you are satisfied with any of the answers you might accept them to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-decoration: underline;`.

```css
div {
font-size: 30px;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
MY NAME HERE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its working and you are getting the output you desire so its ok but if you don't need manually set line thickness you can simply use the following:

```
div {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[Simple fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0bwyjv79/)

Comment: Are you sure? Please check fiddle. Or maybe you wanted to achieve something else besides underline?

Comment: I'm sorry. Truly I am.

Comment: No problem, mistakes happen :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text-decoration {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.border-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed orange;
  padding
}

.text-shadow {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.85;
  text-shadow: 0 0 #fff 
}
```

```html
You can use:<br><br>

<span class="text-decoration">text-decoration</span><br>
<span class="border-bottom">border-bottom</span><br>
<span class="text-shadow">text-shadow</span><br>
```

or the once deprecated and now [re-introduced in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u) `<u>` element, if that's suits best your semantics:

```
<u>semantic element</u>
```